# Hive Passing Property/Text File to read Multiple Variable values in -hiveconf

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Currently I am able to use the below command:

```
hive -f hive-job.hql -hiveconf city='CA' -hiveconf country='US'
```

Here I am passing only 2 variable values. But I have around 15 to 20 variable values which I need to pass it through **-hiveconf**. These values are stored in a **properties/text**  file.

Is there a possible way to read the file through -hiveconf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to add the property value to Hive variables. But there are two ways which I know might be helpful:

1.) Keep all the variables in hive-job-varibales.hql file as

```
set x=1;

set y=2;
...
Then call this file in the main file i.e hive -f hive-job.hql like this:

select ... from ..
...
hive-job-varibales.hql
```

2.) Use Java code to read from property files and convert the property values to hive variable format and use Hive JDBC connection to connect to Hive Server and run your queries in the order you want.

As per your requirement I would suggest to use the second option.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Thanks Mukesh!! I am trying 1st Option at my end.
I already have a Java Implementation for the same (as mentioned in your second option). Will update you further on this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using shell tools pretty easily.

Assuming your properties file is in typical "key=val" format, e.g.

```
a=1
b=some_value
c=foo
```

Then you can do:

```
sed 's/^/-hiveconf\n/g' my_properties_file | xargs hive -f hive-job.hql
```